Select menu does not update highlight when options changes
I have a select menu with dynamic options. Something like this:
<select>
  {options}
</select>

On page load I fetch the user's current country and render this:
<select>
  <option value="italy">Italy</option>
</select>

When the select-element is focused, I fetch all available countries:
(I'm not fetching it together with current country to reduce page loading time)
<select>
  <option value="england">England</option>
  <option value="france">France</option>
  <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
  <option value="spain">Spain</option>
  <option value="germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="italy">Italy</option>
</select>

Problem
If the dropdown menu is open while the options get swapped out, the highlight will stay on the same position (selectedIndex doesn't update according to the new value="italy" position)



How to reproduce
Browser: Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge

Go to this Codesandbox
Click on the select menu
Observe

Desired result
I want the highlight to move to the 'Italy' option after option swap.
Attempts
I tried modifying the selectedIndex:
useEffect(() => {
  if (optionsAreLoaded) {
    selectRef.current.selectedIndex = 6
  }
}, [options]);

But that didn't do anything to the highlight

I also saw this similar question. In it, the OP answered themselves saying they had to reset the select value whenever the option list changed. So I tried this:
useEffect(() => {
  setSelectedOption({ id: undefined, value: "", label: "" });
}, [options]);

But again, no effect to the highlight.
Question
Can I update the highlight position while the menu is open?
Do I maybe need to build my own select menu from scratch or use a library (React-select/Mantine/etc.)?
